# Как программно размонтировать (отключить) USB hdd на android?

Tags: android

Имеется:
Планшет LG G-Pad 8 android 5.0.2, к нему подключен USB HDD с отдельным питанием, при отключении питания HDD планшет, естественно, теряет устройство. Проблема в том, что при включении питания диск обратно не монтируется. Если вручную перед отключением питания размонтировать диск, то при включении все работает.
Вопрос:
Как программно можно размонтировать USB без задействования пользователя?